# Complex analysis: Roots less than unity

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that if $be^{a+1}<1$ where $a$ and $b$ are  positive and real then $z^ne^{-a}-be^z=0$ has $n$ zeroes in unit circle.

I am not sure how to proceed? Any Hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an easy consequence of Rouche's Theorem. Let $f$ denote the LHS. $|be^{z}|(=|f(z)- z^{n}e^{-a}| )<|z^{n}e^{-a}|$ on $|z|=1$ so $f(z)$ and $z^{n} e^{-a}$ have the same number of zeros inside the circle.